# iOS NSMutabledictionary is null when I setValue and forKey

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, nsmutabledictionary

I know I may been doing something very stupid but I can not figure out where is the error on this code:

```
NSString *string=@"some string";
[self.dataResponse setValue:string forKey:@"Code"];
```

Also I tried:

```
NSString *string=@"some string";
[self.dataResponse setObject:string forKey:@"Code"];
```

but in both cases my nsmutable dictionary self.dataResponse is null. Any of you knows what I'm doing wrong?

I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Is the dictionary instantiated before adding objects to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to Alloc and Init the NSMutableArray to set values in it. Example:

```
self.dataResponse = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; // This is alloc and init

NSString *string = @"Some Val";
[self.dataResponse setValue:string forKey:@"Code"];
```

Answer (score 0):

your variable self.dataResponse is just nil.

You have to say

```
self.dataResponse = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

to allocate and instantiate a dictionary.

afterwards you can assign values to the keys!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must not have initialised your mutable dictionary yet, wether using alloc/init or a convenience initialiser. Until you do that, setting any object for key will do nothing. You can do this lazily or in view did load (amongst other places).